# How to move node_modules folder out of project root

Tags: visual-studio-2013, npm, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a Visual Studio Project which includes a node_modules folder so I can run Gulp Watch.

The node_modules folder is excluded from the project, but it is still in the root directory of the project.  The issue is that Visual Studio still watches all the directories in the root of the project.  This many files results in very slow operations when doing things such as renaming a file in the Solution explorer or deleting a file.  It can take as long as 60 seconds when it should take about 1 second.

Is there a way to move these files elsewhere and still have gulp run as expected?

Comment: Is there a way instead to tell visual studio to not watch that folder? seems all the editors I use have that option (but i don't use visual studio)

Comment: The best I have found is excluding it from the project.

Comment: That's the wording on the option in sublimetext, it omits it from the file list, but the folder is still there.

Comment: Are you sure the delay is from this? I know that node_modules can be quite big, but we also keep them under the visual studio project root and we don't see such big delays.

Comment: @LiviuCostea, good point.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This now seems to have been resolved:

1. I made sure that the "Show all files" option in Solution Explorer is NOT checked.
2. I created a fresh workspace with only the project files in it.  The prior workspace had gotten message and contained several different versions of the same project in different locations, and this seemed to contribute to the issue.